# Toggle DIV in a UIWebView using a UIButton?

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uibutton

I am developing an app that contains a UIWebView. I want the user to be able to click on a UIButton (or UIButtonBarItem) that will trigger a div element within the UIWebView to toggle on and off (using jQuery - `$('shade').toggle();`). Is this possible?

***Names of elements..***
UIWebView = *`forumIndex`*
UIButtonBarItem = *`forumMenuTrigger`*
The id of the div inside of the UIWebView = *`#shade`*

[image]

Comment: In the handler for the UIButton, you inject JS into the UIWebView (look at the API for UIWebView). This is possible.

Comment: Are you able to give me an example of how I could inject `$('shade').toggle();` into the UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the handler for `UIButton`, you need to somehow grab the reference of the `UIWebView`. I assume you can do that on your own.

Let `forumIndex` be the name of the `UIWebView`. Use [`- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a) method to inject JavaScript into the `UIWebView`.

```
[forumIndex stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"$('#shade').toggle();"];
```

Comment: I am using the following code in my ViewController.m file, the NSLog text outputs, but the div element is not toggling? Where have I gone wrong? 

`- (IBAction)forumMenuToggle:(id)sender{
    [forumIndex stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"$('#shade').toggle();"];
    NSLog(@"forumMenuToggle button is linked..");
}`

Comment: Fixed it, I used `$('shade').toggle();` instead of `$('#shade').toggle();`.

Comment: @Enigmo: You are selecting a div by ID, right? So `#` needs to be there. Not sure why you can select it with `$('shade')`

Comment: Not sure why it worked without the `#`.. Very strange.. One more question (sorry to be a pain in the ass). How to I toggle 2 div elements? I tried this `[forumIndex stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"$('shade').toggle();$('user_navigation').toggle();"];` which didn't work. So I tried `[forumIndex stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"$('shade').toggle();"]; [forumIndex stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"$('user_navigation').toggle();"];` which again, didn't work. Any clue what I'm doing wrong again?

Comment: @Enigmo: You are selecting by tag name! Are you sure you want to select by tag name? If it is id, then `$('#user_navigation')`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

Providing you have an IBAction set for when the UIButton is tapped you can do something in the IBAction method like this:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('#shade').toggle();"];
```

I'm assuming here that your view controller has defined the webview as a property (in this case "webView") - replace it with whatever is appropriate.